# How do I find the constant term of a multivariate polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

So let's say `f[x_, y_] := (2 x + 2 y + 1)^2`, when I type `Coefficient[f[x, y], x y]` I receive `8`. But what can I input to receive `1`, when `(x^0) (y^0)`? Thanks!

Comment: Look up `CoefficientArrays[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pardon me if I misunderstand your request.

```
{0, 0} /. CoefficientRules[f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
Fold[Coefficient[##, 0] &, f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
CoefficientList[f[x, y], {x, y}][[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Or far more elegantly in this case as [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) recommends in a comment:

```
f[0, 0]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question

Comment: In fact, since it's a polynomial, even the humble `f[0, 0]` works nicely.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I never thought about that

Comment: @J. M. Now I feel foolish. :-(

Comment: Not too late to edit, Wiz. ;)